# regular expression - validate email

Tags: pcre

I don't understand this. I hope somebody could explain.

I was coding up a user registration form for a client website.

I was looking for a regular expression to validate the email id.

I found this on one of the websites. Below is the expression -

/^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(.\w{2,3})+$/;

What I don't understand is why is that the author has escaped period(.) with a backslash() multiple times throughout the expression even though the delimiter is slash(/).

My understanding is that we have to escape with a backslash only if we want to use a delimiter within the expression.

Please help understand

Comment: [Don't do it, man. Put down the regex and just walk away.](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 0):

The rules you mentioned regarding escaping delimiters is probably based on the language you're writing in (perl?) because the delimiter (/) character is "special" in the context of that language (or at least in the context of using regex patterns in that language).

However there are several characters that are special within the context of the regular expression pattern itself and one of those is the period (.) character which matches ANY character.  So, if you want to match an actual period in your regular expression you have to escape it with a backslash for the sake of the regular expression parser, not the language parser.

For example in the pattern you provided, without the period in that last character grouping escaped (`(.\w{2,3})+$`), the regular expression would match ANY character (`.`) followed by 2 or 3 word characters (`\w` = A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _) one ore more times (`+` = one or more of previous group, character set, etc.).

So, without the backslash that last character grouping pattern matches ".bc", ".bcd", and "abcd".  But, when the period is escaped with a backslash (`\.`) it becomes a literal period and the pattern no longer matches "abcd".